# Some error i am facing after rendering

Tags: modeling

So i was just moddeling a pistol but in rendering process i am getting some errors and weird stuff going onto my mesh please help[image: it is the thing i am getting in rendering] those weird line their are not expected

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have an extra face you didn't want, try deleting it.

Comment: The face what is bugging is too complicated and may be doesn't flat, what can cause artifacts like this. Try to use only traingles and quadrants when create the mesh. So when you create hollows like this try to cut the whole mesh with edge loops to avoid the extraordinary faces.

Comment: ah thanks i would try